# Laravel Resources routes performace or benefits

Tags: laravel, routes

Does the laravel `Resource Route` give ANY benefit over the 'normal' way of writing routes other than saving time?

ex

```
Route::get('something', 'MyController@index')->name('app.index');
Route::put('something/{thing}', 'MyController@store')->name('app.store');
Route::get('something/{thing}', 'MyController@show')->name('app.show');
```

vs

```
Route::resource('something','MyController')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit is, that you don't have to write them by yourself. If you are using a **Resource Controller** or a Controller with **Resource** logic, the **Resource Routes** come in handy. You can even use **partial** Resource Routes.

The downside is, that you will need to apply Route specific Middleware in your Controller.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers